# Completion of "Dark Angel" storyline?

Tags: tv, dark-angel

The series [Dark Angel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Angel_%28TV_series%29) (starring Jessica Alba) was cancelled mid-storyline.  Is there any official information about what would have happened if the show continued?  (For example, novelisations, statements from producers/writers).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. There were 3 novels written: a prequel titled *Before the Dawn* and two books that pick up where Season 2 left off, *Skin Game* and *After the Dark*.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Angel_%28TV_series%29#Spinoffs)

Answer (score 1):

There's been talks on and off about some sort of continuation, possibly in the form of a movie, but given how long it's been...it seems unlikely anything will happen.

A few online groups have tried to raise support for a continuation. Barcode Day is one such effort. Otherwise, the only official ending is what's written in the books. (...or fanfiction, if you refuse the book endings.)